# For Java streams, does generate + limit guarantee no additional calls to the generator function, or is there a preferred alternative?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a source of data that I know has `n` elements, which I can access by repeatedly calling a method on an object; for the sake of example, let's call it `myReader.find()`.  I want to create a stream of data containing those `n` elements.  Let's also say that I don't want to call the `find()` method more times than the amount of data I want to return, as it will throw an exception (e.g. `NoSuchElementException`) if the method is called after the end of the data is reached.

I know I can create this stream by using the [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range(int,int)) method, and mapping each element using the `find` method.  However, this feels a little weird since I'm completely ignoring the int values in the stream (I'm really just using it to produce a stream with exactly `n` elements).

```java
return IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> myReader.read());
```

An approach I've considered is using [`Stream.generate(supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)) followed by [`Stream.limit(maxSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)).  Based on my understanding of the `limit` function, this feels like it should work.

```java
Stream.generate(myReader::read).limit(n)
```

However, nowhere in the API documentation do I see an indication that the `Stream.limit()` method will guarantee exactly `maxSize` elements are generated by the stream it's called on.  It wouldn't be infeasible that a stream implementation could be allowed to call the generator function more than `n` times, so long as the end result was just the first `n` calls, and so long as it meets the API contract for being a short-circuiting intermediate operation.

### [Stream.limit JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long))

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, truncated to be no longer than maxSize in length.
> This is a short-circuiting stateful intermediate operation.

### [Stream operations and pipelines documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)

> An intermediate operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may produce a finite stream as a result. [...] Having a short-circuiting operation in the pipeline is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for the processing of an infinite stream to terminate normally in finite time.

Is it safe to rely on `Stream.generate(generator).limit(n)` only making `n` calls to the underlying generator?  If so, is there some documentation of this fact that I'm missing?

And to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what *is* the idiomatic way of creating a stream by performing an operation exactly `n` times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream.generate` [creates an *unordered* Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-). This implies that the subsequent `limit` operation is not required to use the first *n* elements, as there is no “first” when there’s no order, but may select arbitrary *n* elements. The implementation may exploit this permission , e.g. for higher parallel processing performance.

The following code

```java
IntSummaryStatistics s =
    Stream.generate(new AtomicInteger()::incrementAndGet)
        .parallel()
        .limit(100_000)
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));

System.out.println(s);
```

prints something like

```
IntSummaryStatistics{count=100000, sum=5000070273, min=1, average=50000,702730, max=100207}
```

on my machine, whereas the max number may vary. It demonstrates that the Stream has selected exactly `100000` elements, as required, but not the elements from 1 to 100000. Since the generator produces strictly ascending numbers, it’s clear that is has been called more than 100000 times to get number higher than that.

Another example

```java
System.out.println(
    Stream.generate(new AtomicInteger()::incrementAndGet)
        .parallel()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

prints something like this on my machine (JDK-14)

```
[4, 8, 5, 6, 10, 3, 7, 1, 9, 11]
```

With JDK-8, it even prints something like

```
[4, 14, 18, 24, 30, 37, 42, 52, 59, 66]
```

---

If a construct like

```
IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> myReader.read())
```

feels weird due to the unused `i` parameter, you may use

```
Collections.nCopies(n, myReader).stream().map(TypeOfMyReader::read)
```

instead. This doesn’t show an unused `int` parameter and works equally well, as in fact, it’s internally implemented as `IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> element)`. There is no way around some counter, visible or hidden, to ensure that the method will be called *n* times. Note that, since `read` likely is a stateful operation, the resulting behavior will always be like an unordered stream when enabling parallel processing, but the `IntStream` and `nCopies` approaches create a finite stream that will never invoke the method more than the specified number of times.

Comment: Great practical answer, thanks! To drive the first example home even further, you here's an example that actually sums the first 100,000 numbers for easy comparison: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100_000).summaryStatistics();`, which returns `IntSummaryStatistics{count=100000, sum=5000050000, min=1, average=50000.500000, max=100000}`

Comment: The [Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) documentation goes into this in some useful detail.  Even for sequential streams, the `limit` method wouldn't be constrained to the first `n` elements generated (though in current implementations, it likely is).  "For sequential streams, [...] if [a stream] is not ordered, repeated execution might produce different results."

Comment: @M.Justin yes, sequential streams do not offer more guarantees, they just have less opportunities to exploit the absence of an encounter order for performance.

Comment: "There is no way around some counter, visible or hidden, to ensure that the method will be called n times." — Depending on how pedantic you want to get, this stream doesn't have a counter (though a counter was used to initially create the queue): `new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(Collections.nCopies(10, myReader)).stream().map(TypeOfMyReader::read)`, since the queue is a linked series of nodes without any stored representation of its size. But that's just nitpicking a very fine answer.

Comment: In that case, it’s hidden in the construction of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` that copies all elements from `nCopies(10, myReader)`…

Answer (score 0):

Only answering the XY-problem part of your question: simply create a spliterator for your reader.

```
class MyStreamSpliterator implements Spliterator<String> { // or whichever datatype
    private final MyReaderClass reader;

    public MyStramSpliterator(MyReaderClass reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<String> action) {
        try {
            String nextval = reader.read();
            action.accept(nextval);
            return true;
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            // cleanup if necessary
            return false;
        }
        // Alternative: if you really really want to use n iterations,
        // add a counter and use it.
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<String> trySplit() {
        return null; // we don't split
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE; // or the correct value, if you know it before
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        // add SIZED if you know the size
        return Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.ORDERED;
    }
}
```

Then, create your stream as `StreamSupport.stream(new MyStreamSpliterator(reader), false)`

Disclaimer: I just threw this together in the SO editor, probably there are some errors.